# "The value violates the MaxLength" error when the dataSource position is changed

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource, richtextbox

so I'm using Winforms and I used a dataSource to link a richTextBox to my database. The problem is, the values for that column are nvarchar(1000). So I limited the richTextBox to 200 characters hoping it would be enough, but with enough font, color change, or chinese characters the rtf string can be way above the maximum for the database (1000).
I made it so it's not possible to save the changes with the save button in the bindingNavigator if the value is too long, but when I change the position of my datasource (with the bindingNavigator), the application crashes with the following message :

> Cannot set column 'COLUMN_NAME'. The value violates the MaxLength
>   limit of this column.

I've seen the same error in many threads but none of them seemed to occur with a change of the position, and I didn't find what I was looking for.
I tried to do things on the click of the button to change the position, but that doesn't change anything.
The exception is thrown to the main program, how can I get it in my class and either disable the changes if the value is too long, or just make it so that it's not stored at all please ?

Here is the whole code (I made a project to recreate the problem).

```
public partial class FormTest : Form
{
    public FormTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.TheFamousBinding();
    }

    public void TheFamousBinding()
    {
        Binding commentBinding = this.richTextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Rtf", this.myBindingSource, "Comment", true);
    }

    private void mODELSBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.myBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.myTableManager.UpdateAll(this.myDataSet);

    }

    private void FormTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.myTableAdapter.Fill(this.myDataSet.myTable);

    }
}
```

And here is the stack trace

> Exception levée : 'System.ArgumentException' dans System.Data.dll
>   'MyProject.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MyProject.exe) : Chargé
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Transactions.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_fr_b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.resources.dll'.
>   Le module a été généré sans symboles. 'MyProject.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: MyProject.exe) : Chargé
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_fr_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll'.
>   Le module a été généré sans symboles. System.Transactions Critical: 0
>   : http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledException
>   non prise en
>   charge3DFlexAdmin.exeSystem.ArgumentException,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Impossible de
>   définir la colonne 'Comment'. La valeur dépasse la limite MaxLength de
>   cette colonne.   à
>   System.Data.DataColumn.CheckMaxLength(DataRow dr)    à
>   System.Data.DataTable.RaiseRowChanging(DataRowChangeEventArgs args,
>   DataRow eRow, DataRowAction eAction, Boolean fireEvent)    à
>   System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecordWorker(DataRow row, Int32
>   proposedRecord, DataRowAction action, Boolean isInMerge, Boolean
>   suppressEnsurePropertyChanged, Int32 position, Boolean fireEvent,
>   Exception&amp; deferredException)    à
>   System.Data.DataRow.EndEdit()    à System.Data.DataRowView.EndEdit()
>   à System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit()    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ChangeRecordState(Int32
>   newPosition, Boolean validating, Boolean endCurrentEdit, Boolean
>   firePositionChange, Boolean pullData)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.set_Position(Int32 value)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.set_Position(Int32 value)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.MoveNext()    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.BindingNavigator.OnMoveNext(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object
>   key, EventArgs e)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e,
>   ToolStripItemEventType met)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e,
>   ToolStripItemEventType met)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp; m,
>   MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;
>   m)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;
>   m)    à System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;
>   msg)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)    à
>   _3DFlexAdmin.Program.Main() dans C:\Users\ADMIN\source\repos\MySolution\MyProject\Program.cs:ligne
>   21System.ArgumentException: Impossible
>   de définir la colonne 'Comment'. La valeur dépasse la limite MaxLength
>   de cette colonne.    à System.Data.DataColumn.CheckMaxLength(DataRow
>   dr)    à System.Data.DataTable.RaiseRowChanging(DataRowChangeEventArgs
>   args, DataRow eRow, DataRowAction eAction, Boolean fireEvent)    à
>   System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecordWorker(DataRow row, Int32
>   proposedRecord, DataRowAction action, Boolean isInMerge, Boolean
>   suppressEnsurePropertyChanged, Int32 position, Boolean fireEvent,
>   Exception&amp; deferredException)    à
>   System.Data.DataRow.EndEdit()    à System.Data.DataRowView.EndEdit()
>   à System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit()    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ChangeRecordState(Int32
>   newPosition, Boolean validating, Boolean endCurrentEdit, Boolean
>   firePositionChange, Boolean pullData)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.set_Position(Int32 value)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.set_Position(Int32 value)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.MoveNext()    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.BindingNavigator.OnMoveNext(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object
>   key, EventArgs e)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e,
>   ToolStripItemEventType met)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e,
>   ToolStripItemEventType met)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp; m,
>   MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;
>   m)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;
>   m)    à System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;
>   msg)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    à
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)    à
>   MyProject.Program.Main() dans C:\Users\ADMIN\source\repos\MySolution\MyProject\Program.cs:ligne
>   21 Une exception non gérée
>   du type 'System.ArgumentException' s'est produite dans System.Data.dll
>   Impossible de définir la colonne 'Comment'. La valeur dépasse la
>   limite MaxLength de cette colonne.
>   Blockquote

Comment: Please show us some code. Particular the one that throws the error. | But if you got a `varchar(1000)` in your DB, the clerly the UI should supprot that. | I also noticed that it is varchar, not **N*varchar, wich is normally used for unicode.

Comment: What happens if the size of the RTF of your RTB *violates* the MaxLength of the Column? Do you cut away some RTF pieces? Or, the other way around, how do you plan to limit the RTF generated by the RTB in the UI side?

Comment: My bad, I already changed it to nvarchar(1000) but wrote varchar because I'm more used to it.
As for the code, I added it but I really don't get how this may help. From the stack trace, it doesn't seem to make it to my code at all.

Comment: Seeing the stack trace might help.  Moving the relevant code out of the constructor and load events could help isolate the problem.

Comment: @Jimi I plan on just deleting the changes if the user changes the position, and setting the value back to what it was before (what's already stored in the database). But I didn't manage to find where to do that, since no matter where I changed it, the exception would still be thrown if the rtf is too long.

Comment: If you check this condition only when the BindingSource changes position, it's too late. You'll have to check the RTF length before that point and maybe call `ResetItem()` if it does. It looks like kind of frustrating, from the User perspective, since a User cannot know when the RTF length grows too much. But you didn't specify what this RTB is for and what it contains or even if a User can actually touch it. Maybe you can simply limit the Text length and don't restrict the RTF length using a fixed value.

Comment: @Jimi So i have to check the rtf length everytime I change the text, or font/color ? If this works, I may leave the text as it is (without the changes that made the string too long). I wanted to delete it because that was probably the easier solution, and I would have figured out later on what to do once I understood the solution.

Comment: Use the [Binding.Parse Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.parse?view=netframework-4.8) to validate the RTF length and adjust the ConvertEventArgs .Value property if the length is too long.